# ¿Cómo creo una tabla de pandas a partir de varias 1D numpy arrays? python

Tags: python, array, pandas, tablas

Parto de varias arrays de 1 dimensión que creé con ***numpy*** tipo:

```
age = np.random.randint(20,85,size=400)
```

Todas las variables como *age* contienen 400 muestras y me gustaría que cada variable fuera una columna de una tabla de pandas (en vertical, cada observación del array una fila nueva).

Lo inteté con vstack:

```
np.vstack(age)
np.vstack(gender)
data = {'Age':[age],'Gender':[gender]}
```

[image: un array por celda]

Pero cada variable ocupa una celda de la tabla cuando yo quiero que cada valor del array se extienda una celda más abajo.

(intento hacer una tabla para mostrar gráficamente el output que quiero pero al menos no se previsualiza de acuerdo a lo que explica el [tutorial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-table-in-so-question)).

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta que a `pandas.DataFrame()` le pases un diccionario cuyas claves sean los nombres de las columnas y cuyos valores sean las series o listas con los datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

# Creemos unos datos aleatorios
age = np.random.randint(20,85,size=400)
gender = [random.choice(("male", "female")) for _ in range(400)]

# Conversión a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"age": age, "gender": gender})

# Resultado
df.head()
```

[image: Resultado]